# Issue with Saving Active Sheet to New workBook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save an Active sheet in Excel using following VBA:

```
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 FName = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DTMForGIS\DTMtoGIS" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh_mm_ss") & ".xls"
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
 Activeworkbook.close
```

but I am having two issues here:
1- When I want to open the file I am encountring with following Message:
[image]

Manually opening the file is OK by pressing the Yes but I am going to use the Excel File in GIS software which causing problem because of misunderstanding of format. As you can see it has .xls format

2- the `Activeworkbook.close` is not functioning since I have to close the Application after running the code by my own!

The first part is very important for me, to understand why this is happening? can you please let me know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong file format.

For `.xls` it is `xlExcel8`. `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` is for `.xlsm`

Either use this

```
FName = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DTMForGIS\DTMtoGIS" & _
        Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh_mm_ss") & ".xls"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
                      FileFormat:=xlExcel8
```

or use this

```
FName = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DTMForGIS\DTMtoGIS" & _
        Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh_mm_ss") & ".xlsm"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, _
                      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Regarding your 2nd question. Change your code to this

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

FName = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\DTMForGIS\DTMtoGIS" & _
Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh_mm_ss") & ".xls"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FName, FileFormat:=xlExcel8

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlValues
    .PasteSpecial xlFormats
End With

Application.Quit
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth but how about my second question? why the Activeworkbook.close ia not closing the original workbook?

Comment: Posting from phone. Please give me few moments. My net is down

Comment: I don't see any problem with that line. The workbook should close. What exact problem are you facing?

Comment: Nothing, but after saving the sheet I have two sheets open! one original sheet and a new created by VBA but not saved as my requested file

Comment: You mean it is not doing a saveas?

Comment: However the new excel file has been saved in requested folder nad application is closed.

Comment: No, Save is fine but The original file and a new fike show up

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43497/discussion-between-behseini-and-siddharth-rout)